# Which of the two following selectors are better?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Considering the following HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a ...
```

**For the same set of declarations, which one of these two rule sets would be more performant?** 
if there is a difference after all

```
ul {
  font-size: 1.25rem
}
```

```
ul a {
  font-size: 1.25rem
}
```

Could be the first one?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the first one, because the web browser doesn't have to make all of the `ul` elements that font size **and the `a` elements that size**.

Comment: What did your benchmarks show?

Comment: The performance gain is negligible. This is such a small example.... but as a best practice less selectors would be better, because it decreases the size of your css file, so the http request for it would be smaller, and with a lower specificity it is probably more efficient... but again... in this example... the gains are basically 0. The 2 rules aren't really comparable though. One styles `<a>` tags and the other styles *anything* inside of a `<ul>`

Comment: Even the footprint and specificity for these selectors are basically a non issue also.

Comment: Yeah, agreed... there should different category for closing questions of this nature.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39519/talks/cssperf/index.html

Comment: And which of the 2 you would use?

Comment: `ul a`, because the intent of what is being styled is more clear. You could have any HTML element inside of a `ul`... no reason to apply a font-size to all of them... that's probably not intended

Comment: what about if you won´t have any other element inside `ul`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul a {
    font-size: 1.25rem
}
```

This is the best if you want to capture every anchor tag or any tag inside `ul/ol` tag

But performance wise,

```
ul {
    font-size: 1.25rem
}
```

this will be best. But if you want to modify the tag's built in css property, like anchor's color property, then you will have to iterate over every child by using 2nd option

Comment: It wouldn't work for `ol`, only `ul`

Comment: It will work for both. I think it's about parent and children relationship. `parent_tag children_tag {css_attribute:attribute_value}`

Comment: You would need `ul a, ol a` to do both